# HorizontalScrollView with snapping effect

Tags: android, gallery, horizontalscrollview, snapping

Is it possible to make HorizontalScrollView with snapping effects for each view inside it?
(Not gallery)

Comment: Have a look at the ViewPager class. There is also a small introduction at the [android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

Comment: I'm familiar with this tutorial. But this enable one page/view every time. I'm looking for a solution that can display multiple views at the same time (like HorizontalScrollView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowdays you should use `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView`.

**Old answer:**

I used this one - http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34
Very fast and compatible with lazy loading.

Comment: Link is down, at least now, so this answer can't be accepted right?

Comment: @AntónioPaulo answered 4 years ago and was found useful by the OP. Anyway, updated the answer for a more modern solution but without example.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use ViewPager instead

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below posts for sample codes. Still, most use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) for the effect.

- http://androidprogrammingmadeeasy.blogspot.jp/2011/08/creating-custom-horizontal-scroll-view.html
- http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/